# Monodroid memory analyzer tool

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

Is there a memory analyzer tool that can be used with monodroid? (some equivalent to MAT for android http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Or is there a way of using MAT (from eclipse) to check memory usage/leaks of a monodroid application ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way:

1. Get the ***dump.hprof*** file using:

   ```
   Debug.DumpHprofData("/sdcard/dump.hprof");
   ```
2. Convert the file so that MAT can read it, using ***hprof-conv*** from ***android-sdk\tools***

   ```
   hprof-conv dump.hprof mat.hprof
   ```
3. Open the ***mat.hprof*** file in MAT

Hope this helps someone :)